# How can I check/uncheck all checkboxes that are in a user control in a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, user-controls

I created a user control to host some checkboxes that are created dynamically based on a list from a SQL table. I need to provide an option to select/unselect all checkboxes. This is easy to do when not created dynamically. The problem I find is that once I click on (ALL), yes, it will check or uncheck all checkboxes, but will not allow individual selection.

The code that generates the checkboxes is this:

```
public void GenerateCheckboxesOnUserControl()
{
    // Create user control.
    UserControl2 flp = new UserControl2();

    UserControl2 userControl2 = new UserControl2();
    userControl2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

    this.customComboBox4.DropDownControl = userControl2.flpanel;


    //*****************************//

    List<string> ItemList = new List<string>();

    ItemList.Add("Pending");
    ItemList.Add("New");
    ItemList.Add("Started");
    ItemList.Add("Declined");
    ItemList.Add("Completed");
    ItemList.Add("Accepted");
    ItemList.Add("Close");
    ItemList.Add("(ALL)");

    int i = ItemList.Count;

    CheckBox[] box = new CheckBox[i];
    _cbStatus = box;

    for (i = 0; i < ItemList.Count; i++)
    {

        box[i] = new CheckBox();
        box[i].Name = "cb" + ItemList[i].ToString();
        box[i].Tag = ItemList[i];
        box[i].Text = ItemList[i].ToString();
        box[i].Focus();

        box[i].BringToFront();
        box[i].CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this._cbStatus_CheckedChanged);

        this.customComboBox4.DropDownControl.Controls.Add(box[i]);
        count++;

    }

    //****************************//
}
```

The code that is used to check/uncheck is this:

```
public void _cbStatus_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is CheckBox == false) return;

    UserControl2 userControl2 = new UserControl2();

    string message = string.Empty;
    string m = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (_cbStatus[i].Checked)
        {
            m += _cbStatus[i].Name + ", ";
            message += string.Format("boxes[{0}] is clicked\n ", i + " " + _cbStatus[i].Name);
        }

        foreach (Control cbStatus in customComboBox4.DropDownControl.Controls)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)cbStatus;
            if (cb.Name == "cb(ALL)" && cb.Checked)
            {
                _cbStatus[i].Checked = true; 
            }
            else
                if (cb.Name == "cb(ALL)" && !cb.Checked)
                {
                    _cbStatus[i].Checked = false;
                }    
        }
    }

    customComboBox4.Text = m;
    //MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

Obviously, if I remove the `foreach` loop, it will allow me to do individual selections. Any suggestion to make it work properly?

[image: Unchecked]
[image: Checked]

This is the codebehind for my user control:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.flpanel = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // flpanel
    // 
    this.flpanel.AutoScroll = true;
    this.flpanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 13);
    this.flpanel.Name = "flpanel";
    this.flpanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(215, 135);
    this.flpanel.TabIndex = 0;
    // 
    // UserControl2
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
    this.Controls.Add(this.flpanel);
    this.Name = "UserControl2";
    this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(222, 151);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);        
}

public System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flpanel;
```

Comment: I can't undestand the problem. Who stops you from clicking the single checkbox to make your individual selection? And if you click the (ALL) checkbox you want all your checkboxes to have the same state (checked or unchecked) of the (ALL) checkbox?

Comment: That foreach loop in the CheckedChanged event handler is pretty broken.  If the All box is not ticked then don't uncheck anything.  Similarly, if the user clicks any checkbox other than All then All ought to be unticked.  Just get rid of the loop completely, only make a click on All do something if it is actually clicked.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I think you are right. Let me try that solution instead. I even think I like it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must only check/uncheck all other checkboxes, if the sender of the check was "cb(All)". And you must omit the "cb(All)" itself in this loop.

So your code should look something like this:

```
var eventSendingCheckbox = sender as CheckBox
if( eventSendingCheckbox.Name == "cb(ALL)" )
{
    foreach( Control cbStatus in customComboBox4.DropDownControl.Controls )
    {
         if( cbStatus != eventSendingCheckbox )
         {
             cbStatus.Checked = eventSendingCheckbox.Checked;
         }
    }
}
```

The real fun begins, if you have the goal to also check/uncheck "cb(ALL)" automatically, if the user manually checked/unchecked all other boxes.